# TF-IDF how to takes only a list of words

Tags: python, tf-idf, stop-words, tfidfvectorizer

I know that we can use a list of stopwords in tf-idf, but is there a way to take only a list of words and neglect the others ?
For example, here a I declare a list of stopwords:
    `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english")`
If I want to just take **cat** and **dog** into account in the sentences, I want something like:
    `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(keep_words=["cat", "dog"])`
My goal is to do text clustering taking into account only specific words ?
Is there a solution ?

Comment: Please provide code also with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. 
say you have an array of words

```
words = ['you','me','we']
TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=words)
```

You can use the vocabulary argument to pass only the selected words.